# Help with understanding definition of Definite Integral

Tags: calculus

I am having some difficulty in understanding notation/meaning in the definition of definite integral. Can you guys help clarify/correct and fill in the gaps in my understanding.

Following is from wikipedia [entry for the Darboux integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral) which is similar to what is in my textbook. My notes are inline.

A partition of an interval $[a,b]$ is a finite sequence of values $x_i$ such that,

$a = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = b $

> Partition to integrate over

Each interval $[x_i−1,x_i]$ is called a subinterval of the partition. Let $ƒ:[a,b]→R$ be a bounded function, and let

$P = (x_0, ..., x_n)$

be a partition of $[a,b]$. Let

> Defining rectangles that would be used to approximate area under curve

$M_i = \sup\limits_{x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)$

$m_i = \inf\limits_{x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)$

> Height of rectangle when above the curve or below the curve respectively

The upper Darboux sum of ƒ with respect to P is

$U_{f,P} = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})M_i$

> sum when using supremum for height

The lower Darboux sum of ƒ with respect to P is

$L_{f,P} = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})m_i$

> sum when using infimum for height

The upper Darboux integral of ƒ is

$U_f = \inf \{U_{f,P} : \mbox{P is a partition of} [a,b]\}$

The lower Darboux integral of ƒ is

$L_f = \sup \{L_{f,P} : \mbox{P is a partition of} [a,b]\}$

> > This is the part that I am unable to understand. What do the infimum and supremum imply here? I understand the definite integral as area under curve. Wouldn't the sums $U_{f,P}$ and $L_{f,P}$ then be the integrals themselves? Why do we need to take the infimum/supremum of these areas?

If $U_ƒ = L_ƒ$, then we say that $ƒ$ is Darboux-integrable and set

$\int_a^b f(t)dt = U_f = L_f$

> this parts seems to intuitively suggest both areas would be nearly equal

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The upper and lower Darboux sums only approximate the area under the curve $(x, f(x))$.  There is no single partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such that $U_{f,P}$ is the exact area, but the approximation keeps getting better as $P$ gets finer.  An equivalent way to say that $f$ is integrable is for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such that $U_{f, P} - L_{f, P} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take infimum and supermum with respect to partitions. Note that $U_{f,P}$ and $L_{f,P}$ depend on $P$. For each $P$, we know that $L_{f,P} \le U_{f,P}$. As $P$ gets finer, $U_{f,P}$ may decrease and $L_{f,P}$ may increase. If there exists a sequence of partition $P_1, P_2, \ldots$ that makes $U_{f,P_n}$ and $L_{f,P_n}$ converge to the same number, that number is taken as the integral. We require that the sequence of partitions must be "increasing" in the sense that all grid points in $P_n$ must be in $P_{n+1}$.

However, there are infinitely many choices of increasing sequences of partitions. If we find a sequence that "doesn't work", that doesn't mean there doesn't exist a sequence that works. To take into account ALL partitions at once, $\sup$ and $\inf$ are used. Note that not only we know that $L_{f,P} \le U_{f,P}$, but we actually know that $L_{f,P} \le U_{f,Q}$ for any partitions $P$ and $Q$. That means every number in the set $\{L_{f,P}|P\text{ is a partition}\}$ is smaller than or equal to every number in the set $\{U_{f,P}|P\text{ is a partition}\}$. If the two set has a common accumulation point, then we can create a sequence of partitions $P_1, P_2, \ldots$ such that $U_{f,P_n}$ and $L_{f,P_n}$ converge to the same number. (Pick once sequence for $U_f$ and one sequence for $L_f$, then create a new partition sequence by taking the union of partitions from both sequences.)

Comment: Thanks. I ignored the idea that there multiple partitions.

Answer (score 3):

$U_{f,P}$ is the area of the upper rectangles and is, generally, bigger than the area under $f$; $L_{f,P}$ is the area of the lower rectangles and is, generally, less than the area under $f$. $U_f$ is the infimum of $U_{f,P}$ over all possible partitions, and $L_f$ is the supremum of $L_{f,P}$ over all possible partitions. If they are equal, then they must equal the integral.